# how to purge wiki pages including entire history from bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, wiki, purge

I am new to bitbucket and would like to know how to purge wiki pages including entire history from bitbucket?
sadly the documentation provided on bitbucket is incomplete or very difficult to understand for me.

their forums are not very responsive, i saw [this page on thier site](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3349) and followed the instructions but still the history is there 
and they have declared that the issue is somehow resolved.

if I do not have reasonably complete handle on deleting data that might have been committed accidentally by me then i will not use such tools.

i might be missing something obvious to the experts, so
any bitbucket experts here to show right path?

Answer (score 0):

You can Clone the wiki to your git client (use `Clone` button in top-right of wiki Home), and delete all files locally and push empty wiki back. This clear all pages, but keeps the history.

Or just delete wiki from repo Settings (set `Wiki settings` to `No wiki`).

Comment: I want to delete the history too. :( but I do need the wiki later

Comment: Then clone it, delete wiki, and recreate new with all pages but without history

Comment: the `clone` then `delete` doesn't delete the history in the first place.

Comment: Cloned repo contain whole history. Create new and move only pages to new